# Call a method inside an object that's inside a php class

Tags: php, class, closures

I need to call a function that's inside an object, inside a class. Of course, for "On The Fly" class methods I'm able to call it using using __call & __set magics but not on this case. Below is the example for this situation.

```
class mainclass
{
public    $v1    = "Hello";
public    $fn    = null;


function    __construct( )
    {
    $this->fn    = (object) [ "fn1"   => null,
                              "fn2"   => null,
                              ];
    }

public  function __call( $name, array $args )
    {
    return  call_user_func_array( $this->$name, $args );
    }

public    function  fn3()
    {
    echo    "This of course works! <br />";
    }
}


$main = new mainclass();

$main->fn4  = function()
    {
    echo    "Even this works! <br />";  
    };

$main->fn->fn1  = function()
    {
    echo    $this->v1 . " World :)";
    };


$main->fn3(); // This of course works!
$main->fn4(); // Even this works!
$main->fn->fn1(); //Call to undefined method stdClass::fn1()
```

There is a possibility to call the function "f1" this way: $main->fn->fn1() ?
If not, any suggestion without drastic changes?

**Unfortunately this is not JavaScript and don't like the way is handled this class but I have to give it a try**

Comment: if a function/closure whatever is stored in `$a->fn->fn1` before the time you need to call it, it should work fine. Else try adding it yourself if it is `null`

Comment: For now, the only solution I have is to use a naming prefix "fn_" and to "attach" the functions directly on the main class: $main->fn_f1 = function() { .... }; Suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only and easy workaround I have for this case is to change the object in anonymous class. During this process you have to store the scope of main class on the internal anonymous class(es) using a similar variable name, "$_this".

```
class mainclass
{
public    $v1    = "Hello";
public    $fn    = null;


function    __construct( )
    {
    $this->fn    = new class( $this)
        {
        public $_this = null;
        public function __construct( $mainscope )
            {
            $this->_this =  &$mainscope;
            }

        public function __call( $method, array $args )
            {
            if  ( isset( $this->{ $method } )  )
                {
                return  call_user_func_array( $this->$method, $args );
                }
            elseif ( isset( $this->_this->{ $name } ) )
                {
                return call_user_func_array( $this->_this->{ $name }, $args);
                }
            }

        public function __set( $name, $value )
            {
            $this->{ $name } = is_callable( $value ) ? $value->bindTo( $this, $this ) : $value;
            }
        };
    }

public  function __call( $method, array $args )
    {
    return  call_user_func_array( $this->{ $method }, $args );
    }

public  function __set( $name, $value )
    {
    $this->{ $name }    = is_callable( $value ) ? $value->bindTo( $this, $this ) : $value;
    }

public    function  fn3()
    {
    echo    "This of course works! <br />";
    }
}


$main = new mainclass();

$main->fn4  = function()
    {
    echo    "Even this works! <br />";  
    };

$main->fn->fn1  = function()
    {
    echo    $this->_this->v1 . " World :)";
    };


$main->fn3(); // This of course works!
$main->fn4(); // Even this works!
$main->fn->fn1(); //Hello World :)
```

**It turns out not very ugly and also manageable.** Anyway this is the only option for now.

Comment: I like the idea! I have to change many variables but is manageable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$main->fn->fn1();
```

`fn1` is an attribute try using `$main->fn`.

Answer (score 0):

`($main->fn->fn1)();` should be working. However, you can't access `$this` in the anonymous function

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I need to keep the scope $this :( If is not possible I have to change everything.